# Scala with maven-plugin can't find depenencies

Tags: spring, scala, maven

I have a scala project using maven. When I was using only scala classes, there was no problem with the maven plugin.
But now, I'm getting errors when trying to compile:

[WARNING] C:\java\workspace\mcare\src\main\scala\com\fb\mcare\config\AppConfig.scala:2: error: object springframework is not a member of package org
[WARNING] import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

```
package com.fb.mcare.config
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class AppConfig {

}
```

my pom:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.fb
    mcare
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    2008
    
        2.9.1-1
        3.1.0.RELEASE
    
    war
    
        
            scala-tools.org
            Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository
            http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases
        
        
            com.springsource.repository.maven.release
            http://maven.springframework.org/release/
            
                false

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tried pretty much everything, what am I missing here?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `<scope>runtime</scope>` from the spring-context dependency in pom.xml.  Runtime scope dependencies are not included on the compile time class path.  See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html for more info on the various scopes.